# Execute SQL Script file with Select query and Dynamic SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a requirement of executing many sql files with dynamic sql queries something like following

**Query1.sql**

```
set @a= (select col_value1 from table1 where x=y);    
set @b= (select col_value2 from table2 where x1=@a);

prepare script from @b;
execute script;
deallocate prepare script;
```

I need to get the ResultSet object after execution for further processing.

I've tried using ScriptRunner from iBatis framework. There we can execute query but no way to get ResultSet object.

Also, seen some method to execute as a System command by RunTime. Since the environment is Thread based, I don't recommend using this approach.

Is there any other way to do this. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just parse your file with regexps and invoke queries with replaced parameters afterwards? I came up with something like like this:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

private static String queryFile() {
    return "set @a= (select col_value1 from table1 where x=y);\n" +
            "set @b= (select col_value2 from table2 where x1=@a);\n" +
            "prepare script from @b;\n" +
            "execute script;\n" +
            "deallocate prepare script;";
}

private static final Pattern QUERY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("set (@.)= (.*.)");
private static final Pattern QUERY_VARIABLE_MATCHER = Pattern.compile("@.");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> queryMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    String lines[] = queryFile().split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        Matcher matcher = QUERY_PATTERN.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String key = matcher.group(1);
            String query = matcher.group(2);
            queryMap.put(key, query);
        }
    }

    invokeQueries(queryMap);
}

/**
 * Invokes queries parsed from a file. Works only if queries are sorted properly (query B uses a query A result).
 */
private static void invokeQueries(Map<String, String> queryMap) {
    Map<String, String> queryResults = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : queryMap.entrySet()) {
        String query = entry.getValue();
        Matcher matcher = QUERY_VARIABLE_MATCHER.matcher(query);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            String queryResult = mockInvokeQuery(query);
            queryResults.put(entry.getKey(), queryResult);
            System.out.println("Invoked query: " + query + " with result : " + queryResult);
        } else {
            matcher.reset();
            System.out.println("Replacing query parameters for query: " + query);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String variable = matcher.group();
                String replacedQuery = query.replaceAll(variable, queryResults.get(variable));
                String queryResult = mockInvokeQuery(query);
                queryResults.put(entry.getKey(), queryResult);
                System.out.println("Invoked query with replaced parameters:: " + replacedQuery + " with result: " + queryResult);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Invoke your query and get your result set
 */
private static String mockInvokeQuery(String query) {
    return String.valueOf(query.hashCode());
}

/**
 * Replaces @ parameter for all queries within a hashmap. It won't work properly if queries are dependent on each other.
 */
private static Map<String, String> replaceQueryVariables(Map<String, String> queryMap) {
    Map<String, String> replacedQueries = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : queryMap.entrySet()) {
        String query = entry.getValue();
        Matcher matcher = QUERY_VARIABLE_MATCHER.matcher(query);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String variable = matcher.group();
            String replacedQuery = query.replaceAll(variable, queryMap.get(variable));
            replacedQueries.put(entry.getKey(), replacedQuery);

        }
    }
    return replacedQueries;
}

}
```

Result is:

```
Invoked query: (select col_value1 from table1 where x=y); with result : -316456543
Replacing query parameters for query: (select col_value2 from table2 where x1=@a);
Invoked query with replaced parameters:: (select col_value2 from table2 where x1=-316456543); with result: -1396099308
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. This was helpful.

Comment: My requirement is slight different.
The second 'set' contains a concat() i.e.
set @b = concat(.... (select a from b where c =@a) ....). If we split and execute separately, the second statement throws an error.